# Check If Custom Class Not Nil --- Swift Is Converting It To A UInt8

Tags: xcode, swift, boolean, null, boolean-expression

[image]

I have a custom image class and I am just trying to check if its not nil.

Every syntax I try (with the above being my best guess) keeps saying my iImage is not a UInt8.

First: why is it thinking by comparing to nil its a UInt8 in the first place?

Second: how can I check if my custom class is nil?

Update:

Answers are appreciated but didn't work. Here is full code block

```
private class func doubleLayoutView(mainView:UIView,images:Array<iImage>)
    {
        for i in 0...1{

            var image:iImage = images[i]
            if image.uiImage!=nil
            {
                image.imageFrame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i)*mainView.frame.width/2, 0, mainView.frame.width/2, mainView.frame.height)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since the error doesn't seem to make sense, I would think it's about trying to compare a non optional to `nil`. Can you show us the definition of `uiImage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a custom image class and I am just trying to check if its not nil

Be sure that `iamge.uiImage` is Optional. Otherwise you can't compare it to `nil`

In this case Swift helps you do avoid extra validation `!= nil`.

On other hand if `uiImage` is not Optional (a.e. marked without `?`) means that this value is not `nil` and you can remove `if` validation statement because it doesn't make sense

> how can I check if my custom class is nil?

If you feel pretty confident that custom class is not `nil` - don't check it. 
If it might be `nil` - define it as Optional like:

```
var uiImage:UIImage?
```

In this case each time when you are going to use it, need to unwrap it 1<sup>st</sup>

Comment: It's not an optional, I updated my example, as you can see I take it out of an array

Comment: @Aggressor if so, remove `if`, you don't need it

Answer (score 4):

You have declared uiImage as non optional:

```
var img: UIImage = UIImage()
```

Being it non optional, it cannot be `nil` - I suggest you reading about [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483)

Interestingly, the error is misleading because you are using parenthesis. This code snippet produces the same error:

```
class MyImage {
    var img: UIImage = UIImage()
}

var x = MyImage()

if (x.img != nil) {

}
```

whereas if you omit the parenthesis :

```
if x.img != nil {

}
```

The error is:

> Cannot invoke != with an argument list of type '(@lvalue UIImage, NilLiteralConvertible)'

which makes a little more sense.

I think the different behavior is because in the first case (with parenthesis) the expression is evaluated as a tuple rather than a logical expression.

Since parenthesis in `if` statements are not required, I suggest you to not use them.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I updated my question with the full code block

Comment: here: `var image:iImage = images[i]` you are explicitly stating that `image` is not an optional, so it **cannot** be nil, and as such you cannot check if it's different than nil. Also, the image is extracted from an array, and an array cannot contain `nil`s. So removing the `if` should solve your problem. If you think that the `if` should be needed depending on your app logic, then you have a design error somewhere else in your code